# iText - HTML to PDF - Image is not displayed in PDF

Tags: c#, itext

We are using `iText.dll` of version v1.4.6.2 to generate a horizontal line from an image file.

The below code generates this horizontal line at our local and live system correctly but now its generating line at local system but not on live system.

```
<div id="'div'_0" type="hrDiv" objtype="10" objtag="" objname="object name" onmouseover="this.className='putpointer'" isitem="" groupid="0" hgroupid="0" associatedlabel="" ishgroupmain="False" canmove="1" lock="false" runat="server" align="left" style="position: absolute; background-color: transparent; display: inline; overflow: hidden; z-index: 10000; left: 41px; top: 122px; width: 720px; height: 25px;" class="putpointer"><img src="http://localhost:1111/images/HorizontalLine.gif" id="'img'_0" type="imgObj" width="720" height="1" style="position: absolute; display: inline; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Code behind

```
PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;
pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader1, fileStream);
PdfContentByte overContent = pdfStamper.getOverContent(1);

if (true)
{
   string str17 = string.Concat(this.strImagepath, "HRline.jpg");
   com.lowagie.text.Image image =    com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(str17);
   image.setAbsolutePosition(single, single1 + 20f);
   image.scaleAbsolute(single2 - single, 1f);
   overContent.addImage(image);
}
```

```
Note: Security patches may be installed on server system.
```

Comment: I don't know that version number of iText, the oldest .NET version I could find, was 4.1.6, from July 2009. And I work at iText! So how old is your version and where did you get it?

Comment: You are probably talking about two different things here: 4.1.6 was the version number assigned from Bruno / iText. (Defined in Document.java or its C# counterpart). The Version 1.4.6.2 is the version of the dll. If you right click on it \ Details \ Fileversion. Both must not correspond.